# C++ algorithm like python's 'groupby'

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11, containers

Are there any C++ transformations which are similar to [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)?

Of course I could easily write my own, but I'd prefer to leverage the idiomatic behavior or compose one from the features provided by the STL or `boost`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct foo
{
        int x;
        std::string y;
        float z;
};

bool lt_by_x(const foo &a, const foo &b)
{
        return a.x < b.x;
}

void list_by_x(const std::vector<foo> &foos, std::map<int, std::vector<foo> > &foos_by_x)
{
        /* ideas..? */
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
        std::vector<foo> foos;
        std::map<int, std::vector<foo> > foos_by_x;

        std::vector<foo> sorted_foos;
        std::sort(foos.begin(), foos.end(), lt_by_x);
        list_by_x(sorted_foos, foos_by_x);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that read `std::map<int, std::vector<foo>> foos_by_x;`? If not, which of the `foo`s among those with equal `x` should be stored in the result map?

Comment: Indeed it should.  Corrected.

Comment: Is the int in map<int,...> supposed to be for values of foo.x?

Comment: Seems like a true equivalent would give you an iterator that emits (value,range) pairs, where range was another pair of iterators to the begin/end elements that have that value.  It would be interesting, but I'm not sure if it would have any practical use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the point of bloating standard C++ library with an algorithm that is one line of code?

```
for (const auto & foo : foos) foos_by_x[foo.x].push_back(foo);
```

Also, take a look at `std::multimap`, it might be just what you need.

**UPDATE:**

The one-liner I have provided is not well-optimized for the case when your vector is already sorted. A number of map lookups can be reduced if we remember the iterator of previously inserted object, so it the "key" of the next object and do a lookup only when the key is changing. For example:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    int         x;
    std::string y;
    float       z;
};

class optimized_inserter {
  public:
    typedef std::map<int, std::vector<foo> > map_type;

    optimized_inserter(map_type & map) : map(&map), it(map.end()) {}

    void operator()(const foo & obj) {
        typedef map_type::value_type value_type;
        if (it != map->end() && last_x == obj.x) {
            it->second.push_back(obj);
            return;
        }
        last_x = obj.x;
        it = map->insert(value_type(obj.x, std::vector<foo>({ obj }))).first;
    }

  private:
    map_type          *map;
    map_type::iterator it;
    int                last_x;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> foos;
    std::map<int, std::vector<foo>> foos_by_x;

    foos.push_back({ 1, "one", 1.0 });
    foos.push_back({ 3, "third", 2.5 });
    foos.push_back({ 1, "one.. but third", 1.5 });
    foos.push_back({ 2, "second", 1.8 });
    foos.push_back({ 1, "one.. but second", 1.5 });

    std::sort(foos.begin(), foos.end(), [](const foo & lhs, const foo & rhs) {
            return lhs.x < rhs.x;
        });

    std::for_each(foos.begin(), foos.end(), optimized_inserter(foos_by_x));

    for (const auto & p : foos_by_x) {
        std::cout << "--- " << p.first << "---\n";
        for (auto & f : p.second) {
            std::cout << '\t' << f.x << " '" << f.y << "' / " << f.z << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "... algorithm that is one line of code."  It's a fair point, but I think if "lines of code" were the threshold that we'd probably forfeit other parts of the standard library too.

Comment: @BrianCain: I think what he needs is a multimap anyway, because it does sort automatically (the one-liner is not efficient assuming the vector is sorted already)

Comment: `What is the point of bloating standard C++ library with an algorithm that is one line of code?` ... You mean `std::min` and `std::max` for example?

Comment: What is the point of giving a hasty answer, and then realize on your own it is not just "an algorithm that is one line of code"?

Comment: This isn't really similar to python's itertools group_by... it creates a map of groups, but python's version creates an iterator of iterators of these groups, so you don't need to hold all these groups in memory, you lazily generate them as you iterate over your container.

Something in the spirit of Ranges' group_by (yay, it's part of the c++20 standard).

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't really answer your question, but for the fun of it, I implemented a group_by iterator.  Maybe someone will find it useful:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::multiset;
using std::ostringstream;
using std::pair;
using std::vector;

struct Foo
{
  int x;
  std::string y;
  float z;
};

struct FooX {
  typedef int value_type;
  value_type operator()(const Foo &f) const { return f.x; }
};



template <typename Iterator,typename KeyFunc>
struct GroupBy {
  typedef typename KeyFunc::value_type KeyValue;

  struct Range {
    Range(Iterator begin,Iterator end)
    : iter_pair(begin,end)
    {
    }

    Iterator begin() const { return iter_pair.first; }
    Iterator end() const { return iter_pair.second; }

    private:
      pair<Iterator,Iterator> iter_pair;
  };

  struct Group {
    KeyValue value;
    Range range;

    Group(KeyValue value,Range range)
    : value(value), range(range)
    {
    }
  };


  struct GroupIterator {
    typedef Group value_type;

    GroupIterator(Iterator iter,Iterator end,KeyFunc key_func)
    : range_begin(iter), range_end(iter), end(end), key_func(key_func)
    {
      advance_range_end();
    }

    bool operator==(const GroupIterator &that) const
    {
      return range_begin==that.range_begin;
    }

    bool operator!=(const GroupIterator &that) const
    {
      return !(*this==that);
    }

    GroupIterator operator++()
    {
      range_begin = range_end;
      advance_range_end();
      return *this;
    }

    value_type operator*() const
    {
      return value_type(key_func(*range_begin),Range(range_begin,range_end));
    }


    private:
      void advance_range_end()
      {
        if (range_end!=end) {
          typename KeyFunc::value_type value = key_func(*range_end++);
          while (range_end!=end && key_func(*range_end)==value) {
            ++range_end;
          }
        }
      }

      Iterator range_begin;
      Iterator range_end;
      Iterator end;
      KeyFunc key_func;
  };

  GroupBy(Iterator begin_iter,Iterator end_iter,KeyFunc key_func)
  : begin_iter(begin_iter),
    end_iter(end_iter),
    key_func(key_func)
  {
  }

  GroupIterator begin() { return GroupIterator(begin_iter,end_iter,key_func); }

  GroupIterator end() { return GroupIterator(end_iter,end_iter,key_func); }

  private:
    Iterator begin_iter;
    Iterator end_iter;
    KeyFunc key_func;
};


template <typename Iterator,typename KeyFunc>
inline GroupBy<Iterator,KeyFunc>
  group_by(
    Iterator begin,
    Iterator end,
    const KeyFunc &key_func = KeyFunc()
  )
{
  return GroupBy<Iterator,KeyFunc>(begin,end,key_func);
}


static void test()
{
  vector<Foo> foos;
  foos.push_back({5,"bill",2.1});
  foos.push_back({5,"rick",3.7});
  foos.push_back({3,"tom",2.5});
  foos.push_back({7,"joe",3.4});
  foos.push_back({5,"bob",7.2});

  ostringstream out;

  for (auto group : group_by(foos.begin(),foos.end(),FooX())) {
    out << group.value << ":";
    for (auto elem : group.range) {
      out << " " << elem.y;
    }
    out << "\n";
  }

  assert(out.str()==
    "5: bill rick\n"
    "3: tom\n"
    "7: joe\n"
    "5: bob\n"
  );
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 ...even though I would've expected `5: bob` to go with `5: bill rick` - this is fixable

Comment: The `while` loop can be changed into a `std::find_if`

Answer (score 9):

Eric Niebler's [ranges library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) provides a [group_by](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/group_by.hpp) view.

according to the docs it is a header only library and can be included easily.

It's supposed to go into the standard C++ space, but can be used with a recent C++11 compiler.

minimal working example:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace ranges;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector<int> l { 0,1,2,3,6,5,4,7,8,9 };
    ranges::v3::sort(l);
    auto x = l | view::group_by([](int x, int y) { return x / 5 == y / 5; });
    map<int, vector<int>> res;

    auto i = x.begin();
    auto e = x.end();
    for (;i != e; ++i) {
      auto first = *((*i).begin());
      res[first / 5] = to_vector(*i);
    }

    // res = { 0 : [0,1,2,3,4], 1: [5,6,7,8,9] }
}
```

(I compiled this with clang 3.9.0. and `--std=c++11`)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412027/haskell-equivalent-to-scalas-groupby

Comment: view::group_by can only group by true and false.

Answer (score 6):

I recently discovered [`cppitertools`](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools).

It fulfills this need exactly as described.

https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools#groupby

Comment: c++14 master: coming 2015

Comment: Doesn't seem like a great implementation compared to how SQL (or LINQ) works.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
template <typename StructType, typename FieldSelectorUnaryFn>
auto GroupBy(const std::vector<StructType>& instances, const FieldSelectorUnaryFn& fieldChooser)
{
    StructType _;
    using FieldType = decltype(fieldChooser(_));
    std::map<FieldType, std::vector<StructType>> instancesByField;
    for (auto& instance : instances)
    {
        instancesByField[fieldChooser(instance)].push_back(instance);
    }
    return instancesByField;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
auto itemsByX = GroupBy(items, [](const auto& item){ return item.x; });
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [C++ library to address this problem](https://github.com/Eleobert/duf) in an elegant way. Given your struct

```
struct foo
{
    int x;
    std::string y;
    float z;
};
```

To group by `y` you simply do:

```
std::vector<foo> dataframe;
...
auto groups = group_by(dataframe, &foo::y);
```

You can also group by more than one variable:

```
auto groups = group_by(dataframe, &foo::y, &foo::x);
```

And then iterate through the groups normally:

```
for(auto& [key, group]: groups)
{
    // do something
}
```

It also has other operations such as: subset, concat, and others.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use [boolinq.h](https://github.com/k06a/boolinq/blob/master/include/boolinq/boolinq.h), which includes all of LINQ.  No documentation, but very simple to use.