# Haskell equivalent to Scala's groupBy

Tags: haskell

Scala has a function `groupBy` on lists that accepts a function for extracting keys from list items, and returns another list where the items are tuples consisting of the key and the list of items producing that key. In other words, something like this:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).groupBy(_ % 2)
// List((0, List(2,4,6,8)), (1, List(1,3,5,7,9)))
```

(Actually, it looks like in current versions it provides a `Map` instead, but that's not important). C# has an even more useful version that lets you map the values at the same time (very useful if, say, your key function is just extracting part of a tuple).

Haskell has a `groupBy`, but it's somewhat different - it groups runs of things according to some comparison function.

Before I go and write it, is there an equivalent of Scala's `groupBy` in Haskell? Hoogle doesn't have anything for what I'd expect the signature to look like (below), but I may have just got it wrong.

```
Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(b,[a])]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write the function yourself rather easily, but you need to place an `Ord` or `Hashable` constraint on the result of the classifier function if you want an efficient solution. Example:

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.List
import Data.Function

myGroupBy :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(b, [a])]
myGroupBy f = map (f . head &&& id)
                   . groupBy ((==) `on` f)
                   . sortBy (compare `on` f)

> myGroupBy (`mod` 2) [1..9]
[(0,[2,4,6,8]),(1,[1,3,5,7,9])]
```

You can also use a hash map like `Data.HashMap.Strict` instead of sorting for expected linear time.

Comment: I made a slight modification to this to give the C# option of applying a function over the values at the same time: `myGroupBy f g xs = map (f . head &&& g) . groupBy ((==) \`on\` f) . sortBy (compare \`on\` f) $ xs`

Comment: @Impredicative: That looks very useful indeed!

Comment: @Impredicative: `myCSharpGroupby f g xs = map (second g) $ myGroupBy f xs` would work also

Comment: It's not an equivalent, because: 1. additional `Ord` requirement; 2. worse time complexity

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, the following should work:

```
scalaGroupBy f = groupBy ((==) `on` f) . sortBy (comparing f)
```

modulo that this doesn't get you the result of `f` in each group, but if you really need it you can always post-process with

```
map (\xs -> (f (head xs), xs)) . scalaGroupBy f
```

Comment: Where is the `using` function defined?

Comment: @NiklasB. Good question, Hoogle does not seem to find it. Yet I'd swear it was there once?! Just like comparing f is f x <=> f y, so using f should be f x == f y

Comment: So basically `equaling` or something. I think `Data.Function.on` is the generalization of these concepts, since `comparing = on compare` and `using = on (==)`

Comment: @NiklasB. I have replaced it by (==) `on`, perhaps I confused something here.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a function in the List library.

You can write it as the composition of sortBy and groupBy.

Answer (score 1):

Since Scala `groupBy` returns an immutable `HashMap`, which does not require ordering, the corresponding Haskell implementation should return a `HashMap` as well.

```hs
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as M

scalaGroupBy :: (Eq k, Hashable k) => (v -> k) -> [v] -> M.HashMap k [v]
scalaGroupBy f l = M.fromListWith (++) [ (f a, [a]) | a <- l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `trace` in `f` reveals that, with @Niklas solution, `f` is evaluated 3 times for each element on any list of length 2 or more.  I took the liberty of modifying it so that `f` is applied to each element only once.  It's not clear however whether the cost of creating and destroying tuples is less than the cost of evaluating `f` multiple times (since `f` can be arbitrary).

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.List
import Data.Function

myGroupBy' :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [(b, [a])]
myGroupBy' f = map (fst . head &&& map snd)
                   . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
                   . sortBy (compare `on` fst)
                   . map (f &&& id)
```

Comment: I don't like that `head` -- I came up with `foldr go [] where go (k, x) (k', xs) | k == k' = (k, x:xs); go (k, x) kxs = (k, [x]) : kxs`, but perhaps that's not clearer.

Comment: (I know the `head` can never crash. But I prefer code that *syntactically* can never crash, instead of having to think about it)

Comment: @BenMillwood, your code doesn't typecheck.  I had the same qualm about using `head` on the sublists that result from `group` or `groupBy`, but now I'm used to it.

Comment: Oh, whoops. `foldr go [] where go (k, x) ((k', xs) : ys) | k == k' = (k, x:xs) : ys; go (k, x) kxs = (k, [x]) : kxs`

Answer (score 0):

This solution will break and group by on (f x), regardless wether it is sorted or not

```
f = (`mod` (2::Int))

list = [1,3,4,6,8,9] :: [Int]


myGroupBy :: Eq t => (b -> t) -> [b] -> [(t, [b])]

myGroupBy f (z:zs) = reverse $ foldl (g f) [(f z,[z])] zs
  where
    -- folding function                        
    g f ((tx, xs):previous) y = if (tx == ty)
                           then (tx, y:xs):previous
                           else (ty, [y]):(tx, reverse xs):previous
        where ty = f y                        

main = print $ myGroupBy f list
```

result:
    [(1,[1,3]),(0,[4,6,8]),(1,[9])]

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the SQL-like `then group by` syntax in list comprehension, which requires `TransformListComp` language extension.

Since Scala `groupBy` returns a `Map`, we can call `fromDistinctAscList` to convert the list comprehension to a `Map`.

```
$ stack repl --package containers
```

```hs
Prelude> :set -XTransformListComp
Prelude> import Data.Map.Strict ( fromDistinctAscList, Map )
Prelude Data.Map.Strict> import GHC.Exts ( groupWith, the )
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts> :{
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts| scalaGroupBy f l =
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts|   fromDistinctAscList
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts|     [ (the key, value)
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts|     | value <- l
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts|     , let key = f value
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts|     , then group by key using groupWith
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts|     ]
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts| :}
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts> :type scalaGroupBy
scalaGroupBy :: Ord b => (t -> b) -> [t] -> Map b [t]
Prelude Data.Map.Strict GHC.Exts> scalaGroupBy (`mod` 2) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
fromList [(0,[2,4,6,8]),(1,[1,3,5,7,9])]
```

The only difference from Scala `groupBy` is that the above implementation returns a sorted map instead of a hash map. For implementation that returns a hash map, see my other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64204797/955091.