# Group duplicate items in vector - c++

Tags: c++, vector

`INPUT : [3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

`OUTPUT : [[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]`

The Input is a vector of int while the Output is a vector of vectors of ints. The aim is to do this in the most efficient possible way in terms of time-taken.

The solution I am currently using is this :

```
vector<vector<int> results;
vector<int> result;

for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size() - 1 ; i++ ){
    result.push_back(list[i]);
    if ( list[i] != list[i+1]){
        results.push_back(result);
        result.clear();
    }
}

result.push_back(list[list.size()-1]);
results.push_back(result);
```

- credit to : @kabanus

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any simple working algorithm will probably be close enough to the most efficient.

Comment: If you dont have anything, the most efficient is really anything that works. Write something that works, only then start thinking about efficiency.

Comment: I do have something But it doesn't work and I am unable to find the error. I'll edit the question to reflect what I have. - Edited : Added what I have.

Comment: The code you show will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - any indications as to why? I am getting weird results so clearly you are right.

Comment: `i+1` - so when i = sorted.size() - 1, i+1 is out of bounds

Comment: as an alternative - use your debugger and step through it - better yet, this one :)

Comment: @UKMonkey - I see what you mean, but even setting the condition to `sorted.size() - 1` doesn't result in any improvement. I am using my debugger and stepping through it but for some reason, my IDE won't show the contents of a STL container.

Comment: Related or dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12335860/3002139

Comment: I dont understand why you look for `sorted[i] == sorted[i+1]` instead of `sorted[i] == sorted[i-1]`. To know if a number belongs to the last or a new cluster it has to be the same as the previous value, comparing it to the next value doesnt help to decide where it belongs. Currently if there is a single element in one cluster you will completely miss it, though that might be intended

Comment: Whatever you do - you're going to be missing 1 element.  I personally would just count the number of items until they change ... and then create the vector of the right size initialised to the right size and values.

Comment: @UKMonkey- For some reason, I didn't think of that. Will give it a shot. :)

Comment: @tobi303 I'm considering re-opening - could you elucidate what's unclear in the question? It wasn't hard at all to understand what OP wanted and fix his code easily. Seems the C/++ community is quite stringent on SO.

Comment: @kabanus it is unclear what is the issue with the code in the question. I think it produces wrong output, in that case the question should include a mcve, input, expected & actual output. Concerning the "most efficient" it is not clear what are the requirements. Is op looking for the fastest or most memory efficient or most readable?

Comment: @tobi303 I agree input/output is missing, but other communities let that stuff slide usually. Also I think the first guess is 'bad output', but I guess I had to infer it.  I'll leave it then, as this is consensus here.

Comment: @kabanus I just recently discovered that there has been a paradigm shift on SO from (sloppy speaking) "questions that will be helpful not only for OP" to "if it helps to fix OPs code, it is OK". I am actually more in favor of the first, but anyhow if it is merely about helping OP to fix the code then it doesnt really matter if the question is closed, no?

Comment: @tobi303 Agreed.

Comment: @kabanus - You seem to be quite correct. I have edited the question to be more clearer and indicate exactly what is the case now. If there's any issue there, please let me know so i can improve. If there is a better solution ( in terms of time efficiency ) then it would be highly appreciated if you would either amend or post an answer.

Comment: @tobi303 - Same as above to you as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're close. You already figured out your bounds problem, but consider what happens at the interface of clusters:

```
..2,2,3,3...
    ^ ^
    i i+1
```

You are going to enter the `else` (`else if` is unnecessary if the condition is the exact opposite of the original `if`) and forget to add that last `2`. If there are no duplicates in the vector, such as

```
`{1,2,3,4}`
```

You are not going to add anything but empty clusters! So, you always want to add the number, rather you're in a cluster or ending it. If you're ending a cluster you **also** want to add it and clear.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < sorted.size()-1 ; i++ ){
    cluster.push_back(sorted[i]);
    if ( sorted[i] != sorted[i+1]){
        clusters.push_back(cluster);
        cluster.clear();
    }
}
```

Finally, as @tobi303 mentioned the last element is missing. This is especially obvious with a list with a single element (`{3}`). Note the last cluster is not added in any case, whether if it's a new single element at the end or just a final cluster.

So, once we exit the `for` we need one more check (not really) - if the cluster is empty that means the last element is not a part of it, and is a new one. Otherwise, the last cluster wasn't added yet and you need to append the last element to it, and then add the cluster. I'm leaving this one up to you.

Comment: your code still has an out-of-bounds access....

Comment: @tobi303 No it doesn't :) Thanks, I just copy - pasted.

Comment: ... now you miss the last element

Comment: @tobi303 Correct. You know you could just edit my answer if it's close enough. thanks though!

Comment: @kabanus - Doing a test on something like this : `[2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` results in this : `[[2,0],[1,1]]` . Any ideas?

Comment: @MacAhmed Running this code without the addition of the last cluster fix results in {{2},{1,1,1,1,1,1}} for me. Double check. Regarding the 0s, I didn't post how to add the last element - it's two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [standard algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) as much as possible

This is a possible implementation:

```
template <class T>
auto make_clusters(std::vector<T>& v) -> std::vector<std::vector<T>>
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> clusters;

    auto cluster_begin = v.begin();
    while (cluster_begin != v.end())
    {
        auto elem = *cluster_begin;

        auto cluster_end = std::find_if(cluster_begin, v.end(),
                                        [&](int e) { return e != elem; });
        clusters.emplace_back(std::distance(cluster_begin, cluster_end), elem);

        cluster_begin = cluster_end;
    }

    return clusters;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bolov. Would you be able to indicate how this would be modified if instead of an int, its a struct with struct.x performing the function that int is here.

Comment: @MacAhmed done. See edit