# How to get the smallest value group by variable value?

Tags: c++

I'm noob in cpp I want to get some help, I want to select the lowest value within a vector which contain these list of object. it kind of select aggregation

```
class Label{
private:
    std::string lbl;
    int n;

public:

    int getN() const { return this->n; }
    std::string getlbl() const { return this->lbl; }

};

int main() {
    std::vector<Label> my_vect = {
    {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0}, 
    {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0}, {"labl02", 232}, 
    {"labl02", 232}, {"labl02", 233}, {"labl02", 234}, 
    {"labl02", 230}, {"labl02", 233}, {"labl02", 234}, 
    {"labl02", 229}, {"labl03", 379}, {"labl03", 377}, 
    {"labl03", 379}, {"labl03", 381}, {"labl03", 380}, 
    {"labl03", 377}, {"labl03", 381}, {"labl03", 372}
    };

    for(auto & v: my_vect)
    {
        cout <<"dis : "<< v.getlbl() <<" value " <<  v.getN() << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope do this aggragation

```
dis : labl07 value 0
dis : labl02 value 229
dis : labl03 value 372
```

in some comments below they use map associative container I need to understand why instead of vectors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ algorithm like python's 'groupby'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335860/c-algorithm-like-pythons-groupby)

Comment: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the vector and just print first elements? If you want to *eliminate* duplicates, apply [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) after sorting...

Comment: I'm not trying to remove duplicates, I want to get the smallest value per lable name in that vector

Comment: @cht_usr Then just don't apply `std::unique`, still, sorting and selecting first occurence of label would do the job. If you have no appropriate `operator <`, you can supply a custom comparator as lambda: `[](Label const& x, Label const& y) { return x.lbl < y.lbl || x.lbl == y.lbl && x.n < y.n; }`

Comment: Do you rely on labels being listed in order of first occurrence in vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use associative container maps in this case, cause using vector is more complex.

```
string labelN;

string val;
int number;

map<string, int> values;  

while (readingInput)  
{
  // input next line
  fileInput >> labelN >>  " ">> val>> "value " >> number;
  if (number> values[val])
  {
     values[val] = number;
   }
}
```

after reading some advice below. I have written this code I think it does the job unless somebody writes a better one. So first, you have to create a constructor of the objects that ganna be added to your vector. 
Second, you have to add a function which will sort your vector in an aggregation way, then insert the result into the map. the last part of the code I pushed the results in vector you might use it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Label{
private:
    std::string lbl;
    int n;

public:
    Label(std::string sp, int np): lbl(sp), n(np) {}
    int getN() const { return this->n; }
    std::string getlbl() const { return this->lbl; }
    static bool sortByn( Label a, Label b )
    {
       if ( a.n < b.n ) return true;
       if ( a.n == b.n && a.lbl < b.lbl ) return true;
       return false;
    }

};

int main() {
    std::vector<Label> my_vect = {
    {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0},
    {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0}, {"labl02", 232},
    {"labl02", 232}, {"labl02", 233}, {"labl02", 234},
    {"labl02", 230}, {"labl02", 233}, {"labl02", 234},
    {"labl02", 229}, {"labl03", 379}, {"labl03", 377},
    {"labl03", 379}, {"labl03", 381}, {"labl03", 380},
    {"labl03", 377}, {"labl03", 381}, {"labl03", 372}
    };

    for(auto & v: my_vect)
    {
        cout <<"dis : "<< v.getlbl() <<" value " <<  v.getN() << endl;
    }

    map<string,int> smallest;
    string lbl;
    int n;

    for(auto & v: my_vect)
    {
        lbl = v.getlbl();
        n = v.getN();
        bool occurredBefore = smallest.count( lbl );
        if ( occurredBefore )
        {
         if ( n < smallest[lbl] ) smallest[lbl] = n;
        }
        else
        {
         smallest[lbl] = n;
        }
    }

   vector<Label> V;
   for ( auto e : smallest ) V.push_back( { e.first, e.second } );
   sort( V.begin(), V.end(), Label::sortByn );
   for ( Label L : V ) cout << L.getlbl() << '\t' << L.getN() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: 1. Desired result is smallest numbers, you select largest. 2. `values[val]` will insert a new pair with value being 0, which, if no negative numbers are entered, will be the minimum (provided 1. already fixed)... You need to use [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), and if second parameter is `false`, *then* update first parameter if value is smaller...

Answer (score 3):

As @Aconcagua has suggested, you can sort the vector using a custom comparator to sort the values of your vector:

```
[](Label const& x, Label const& y) { 
            return ((x.getlbl() < y.getlbl()) || 
                   ((x.getlbl() == y.getlbl()) && (x.getN() < y.getN()))); };
```

You also need a constructor to construct the objects that will be inserted in the vector:

```
Label(std::string label, int value) : lbl(label), n(value){}
```

and when you iterate over all the values just print the element whenever the label is a different one. Thus, the code can look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class Label{
private:
    std::string lbl;
    int n;

public:
    Label(std::string label, int value) : lbl(label), n(value){}
    int getN() const { return this->n; }
    std::string getlbl() const { return this->lbl; }

};

int main() {
    std::vector<Label> my_vect = {
    {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0}, 
    {"labl07", 0}, {"labl07", 0}, {"labl02", 232}, 
    {"labl02", 232}, {"labl02", 233}, {"labl02", 234}, 
    {"labl02", 230}, {"labl02", 233}, {"labl02", 234}, 
    {"labl02", 229}, {"labl03", 379}, {"labl03", 377}, 
    {"labl03", 379}, {"labl03", 381}, {"labl03", 380}, 
    {"labl03", 377}, {"labl03", 381}, {"labl03", 372}
    };

    std::sort(my_vect.begin(), my_vect.end(), [](Label const& x, Label const& y) { 
        return ((x.getlbl() < y.getlbl()) || ((x.getlbl() == y.getlbl()) && (x.getN() < y.getN()))); });

    std::string labelToPrint;

    for(const auto& v: my_vect)
    {
        if (labelToPrint.compare(v.getlbl()) != 0)
        {
            std::cout <<"dis : "<< v.getlbl() <<" value " <<  v.getN() << std::endl;    
            labelToPrint = v.getlbl();  
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only drawback: the vector is modified, output of labels is not necessarily in the order of first occurrence in unsorted vector (thus my second comment asking for relevance). This may be an issue or not, but has to be kept in mind.

Answer (score 1):

you can use multimap to do this, consider following example (and comments)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

struct x{
    std::string s_value;
    int i_value;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<x> v{
        {"01", 11},
        {"02", 9},
        {"03", 27},
        {"01", 3},
        {"02", 7},
        {"03", 34},
        {"01", 2},
        {"02", 6},
        {"03", 11},
    };
    // get unique keys
    std::vector<std::string> keys {};
    for(auto& x_value: v){
        // if key is not present in keys yet put it there
        if(std::find(keys.begin(),keys.end(), x_value.s_value) == keys.end()){
            keys.push_back(x_value.s_value);
        }
    }
    std::multimap<std::string, int> mmap;
    for(auto& x_value : v){
        //put values from vector into multimap
        mmap.insert( decltype(mmap)::value_type(x_value.s_value, x_value.i_value) );
    }

    for(auto& key : keys){
      // for each value we expect to be in multimap get range of values
      std::vector<int> values{};
      auto range = mmap.equal_range(key);
      // put vaules for range into vector
      for(auto i = range.first; i!= range.second; ++i){
          values.push_back(i->second);
      }
      // sort vector
      std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
      // print the least value in range corresponding to key, if there was any
      if(!values.empty()){
        std::cout<<key<<" "<<values[0]<<std::endl;
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While [asdoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6124078/azdoud)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51399941/1312382) technically being correct (referring to edit, revision 3), it uses multiple map lookups which can be avoided by the following variant of:

```
for(auto & v: my_vect)
{
    int n = v.getN();
    // pre-C++11 variant:
    //auto entry = smallest.insert(std::make_pair(v.getlbl(), n));
    // since C++11:
    auto entry = smallest.emplace(v.getlbl(), n);
    if(!entry.second)
    {
        if(n < entry.first->second)
            entry.first->second = n;
    }
}
```

Further improvement: Strings are yet copied, which actually is not necessary, as the map does not live longer than the vector, which contains the strings. So if `lbl` is returned as const reference, we could use `std::reference_wrapper<std::string>` as map keys (or even `char const*` with appropriate custom comparator).

Comment: `emplace(..)` might replace `insert(std::make_pair(..))`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. Even after so many years trying best to get up to date in mind, too, sometimes falling back into pre-C++11 times...

Comment: And in C++17, `if (auto [it, inserted] = smallest.emplace(v.getlbl(), n); !inserted) { it->second = std::min(n, it->second);}`

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, I recall the variables scoped to if, forgot them again while waiting for a compiler being compatible to... But sure, that's cool!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library:

```
auto groups = my_vect | ranges::view::group_by(
   [](const Label& l1, const Label& l2){ return l1.getlbl() == l2.getlbl(); });

for (const auto & group : groups) {
   auto min = ranges::min(group,
      [](const Label& l1, const Label& l2){ return l1.getN() < l2.getN(); });

   std::cout << min.getlbl() << ": " << min.getN() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
labl07: 0
labl02: 229
labl03: 372
```

Note that for higher performance `getlbl()` shoud return by const reference.

Comment: You can even use *projection* instead of lambda: `ranges::min(group, std::less<>{}, &Label::getN)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 It would be then nice to have a projection option even for the `group_by` view, such as we could write `| ranges::view::group_by(std::equal_to<>{}, &Label::getlbl)`.