# Do C++20 ranges support group by functionality?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Sometimes it is quite useful to group/partition the objects based on value of one of their member functions(either getter or some computation).

Do C++20 ranges enable something like

```
std::vector<Person> {{.Age=23, .Name = "Alice"}, {.Age=25, .Name = "Bob"}, {.Age=23, .Name = "Chad"}};
// group by .Age and put into std::map
std::map<int/*Age is int*/, std::vector<Person>> AgeToPerson = ...;
// 23 -> Person{23,Alice}, Person{23,Chad}
// 25 -> Person{25,Bob}
```

Note 1:  there is this old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335860/c-algorithm-like-pythons-groupby) where accepted answer is to just use raw for loop

Note 2: range-v3 has this confusing group_by algorithm that seems useless for my task:

> Given a source range and a binary predicate, return a range of ranges where each range contains contiguous elements from the source
> range such that the following condition holds: for each element in the
> range apart from the first, when that element and the first element
> are passed to the binary predicate, the result is true. In essence,
> views::group_by groups contiguous elements together with a binary
> predicate.

Comment: There isn't a `group_by` facility in c++20. Do you want to know how to do this with range-v3?

Comment: you could use `transform` and then `to_<std::map<int/*Age is int*/, Person>>() ` when you are using `ranges-v3`

Comment: @cigien range-v3 is ok if it is not in parts of range-v3 that made it into C++20

Comment: I'm guessing you actually want `map<int, vector<Person>>` or something? Given that multiple people can have the same age.

Comment: @Barry yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really three different kinds of functionalities that languages offer under the name group by:

1. Take a binary predicate (`(T, T) -> bool`) and group consecutive elements for which that predicate evaluates to true (e.g. Haskell, Elixir, D, range-v3 kind of)
2. Take a unary function (`T -> U`) and group consecutive elements with the same "key" and yield a range of pairs of `U, [T]` (e.g. Rust, Python, also D, F#)
3. Take a unary function (`T -> U`) and return a dictionary that maps `U: [T]` (e.g. Clojure, Kotlin, Scala).

The first two require *consecutive* elements - meaning you need to sort by key. The last one doesn't, since you're producing a container anyway. You could also produce the 3rd version from the 2nd, even without sorting, although that would still require a loop<sup>†</sup>.

But as mentioned, range-v3 only offers the 1st, and that one isn't even in C++20. So you need to write your own thing. In this case, a loop is probably best:

```cpp
template <range R, indirectly_unary_invocable<iterator_t<R>> F>
    /* other requirements such that you can form a map */
auto group_by_into_map(R&& range, F&& f)
{
    unordered_map<
        decay_t<indirect_result_t<F&, iterator_t<R>>>, // result of unary function
        vector<range_value_t<R>>                       // range-as-vector
    > map;

    for (auto&& e : range) {
        map[std::invoke(f, e)].push_back(e);
    }

    return map;
}
```

Something to that effect. This allows:

```cpp
group_by_into_map(people, &Person::Age);
```

---

<sup>†</sup>Unless you're ok with using `std::unordered_multimap`. Do people use that? It's kind of a weird container. But assuming you are, then this is much easier. You can write your own adapter:

```cpp
template <typename F> // NB: must be unconstrained
auto group_by_into_map(F&& f) {
    return views::transform([=](auto&& e){ return std::pair(std::invoke(f, e), e); })
         | ranges::to<std::unordered_multimap>();
        
}
```

which allows for:

```cpp
people | group_by_into_map(&Person::Age);
```

But this gives you an `unordered_multimap<int, Person>` rather than an `unordered_map<int, vector<Person>>`.

Comment: Thank you for nice intro, idk that people/lanugages use different kinds of group by, I always thought SQL way is the only way.

Regarding unordered_multimap, open link below search for is_permutation, try to not cry, cry a lot... ;)
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/operator_cmp

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Well, sure, how else would you compare `==` given that there are no ordering guarantees?

Comment: I would have never added unordered_multimap to STL. But yes obviously if you have it and you can not allocate any extra memory is_permutation is best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `ranges-v3`, you can use a combination of `transform` and `to` to achieve this:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

std::vector<Person> persons{
{.Age=23, .Name = "Alice"}, 
{.Age=25, .Name = "Bob"}, 
{.Age=23, .Name = "Chad"}};

// group by .Age and put into std::map
auto AgeToPerson = persons
    | ranges::view::transform([](const auto& person)
        {
            return std::pair{person.Age, person};
        })
    | ranges::to<std::map<int, Person>>();
```

keep in mind that with this approach you are only getting one `Person` per age, which is why you are probably want to use a `std::multimap` instead of a `std::map`

Comment: Yeah my  bad I should have specified it should be a map from int to std::vector<Person>... my bug, sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

C++23 has views::chunk_by() which returns a range of ranges and accepts a range as input and possibly a predicate or a projection.

```
struct P{int a,b;};

vector<P> v = {{.a=1, .b=1}, {.a=1, .b=2},{.a=2,.a=1}};

auto rg = views::chunk_by(v, &P::a);

/*rg={
{{.a=1, .b=1}, {.a=1, .b=2}},
{{.a=2,.a=1}}
};*/
```